# Multiple values on 1:st index in array

Tags: arrays, smalltalk, visualworks

I'm trying to add lines in a menu. The object I try to change is an Core.Array. And it's named groupSizes.

I'm trying to do like this:

```
((((UI.Menu current builder menuAt: #baseMenu) atNameKey: #menu6axisSpecialTool) submenu menuItems at: 5) submenu) groupSizes at: 1 put: #(4 1 9 4)
```

But that just puts a new array in side the array (logical). And "add:" don't work.
I think I wish to achive something like this:

```
((((UI.Menu current builder menuAt: #baseMenu) atNameKey: #menu6axisSpecialTool) submenu menuItems at: 5) submenu) at: groupSizes put: #(4 1 9 4)
```

But that don't work either. I can inspect the object and manually change the array from (18) to my desired (4 1 9 4). To confim that the change will achive what I wish.

Oh, this will be a change that is applied to the image by fileIn from an external .st-file. Thats why I can't change how it's created, (that and the fact that I barely know what I'm doing.) and wish to manipulate the values inside the array.

I'm 100% green on smalltalk. So I attached a picture that might say more then my words.
[image]

Any idéas of how to change the value of that array?

On closer examination, this is more likely what i wish to do:

```
((((UI.Menu current builder menuAt: #baseMenu) atNameKey: #menu6axisSpecialTool) submenu menuItems at: 5) submenu) groupSizes at: 1 put: 4.
((((UI.Menu current builder menuAt: #baseMenu) atNameKey: #menu6axisSpecialTool) submenu menuItems at: 5) submenu) groupSizes at: 2 put: 1.
((((UI.Menu current builder menuAt: #baseMenu) atNameKey: #menu6axisSpecialTool) submenu menuItems at: 5) submenu) groupSizes at: 3 put: 9.
((((UI.Menu current builder menuAt: #baseMenu) atNameKey: #menu6axisSpecialTool) submenu menuItems at: 5) submenu) groupSizes at: 4 put: 4.
```

But the array don't have index 2-4, how can I increase the number of index:es?

Comment: Have you tried sending the message `groupSizes: #(4 1 9 4)`? From the image you pasted it looks like `groupSizes` is an ivar so the setter should work. If it doesn't look for any other method in the class changing it and try that instead.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't be so rude to your Objects. What you try to achieve is to modify a menu, so what you should be doing is kindly ask the menu to perform the changes or create a new menu instead.
What you shouldn't be doing is modify the data that the menu operates on.

---

But first things first: You ask how you can add to an Array and the answer is simple: You can't!
Arrays are meant to be created at a fixed size and not change their size ever. If you create an Array via: `Array new: 4` you can access the slots 1 to 4 and put anything in it that you like. But if you try to do `anArray add: 1` you'll get an Error via: `self shouldNotImplement`. Now the comment of the method `#add:` is along the lines of *"yeah, you really shouldn't"*, which is absolutely not helpful. Even the class-comment doesn't say a word about *"why"*.
Among other things, Arrays are used for passing data to/from the VirtualMachine, where it's easier to keep things simple instead of having complicated objects (dealing with growth is pretty complicated stuff).

If you need a collection that can grow and behave a lot like Arrays, use `OrderedCollection`. They can grow, they can shrink, you can add to them or remove from them. `OrderedCollection` is basically the go-to Collection for when you need a list of things.

For more information on Collections, you should have a look at the BasicLibraries.pdf in your VisualWorks' installation's `doc` folder. Chapter 1 explains the various `Collection` subclasses. The most common classes that you may be using are: `OrderedCollection`, `Dictionary` and `Set`. `Set` you'll use almost never, `Dictionary a bit more and` OrderedCollection`a lot more. Most of the other Collections are rarely needed. It's good to have an overview of what's there, but you really don't need most of them.`SortedCollection`used to be used more frequently back in the days. Nowadays it's easier to just sort any collection via`#sorted:` and not bother with SortedCollection at all.

So to answer your Question:

> Any idéas of how to change the value of that array?

The answer is simply: Don't even try.

---

To answer your actual question:

> I'm trying to add lines in a menu.

There're other things you can do:

1. Menus are resources, so there's probably a method that describes the menu somewhere on class-side of an `ApplicationModel`. You can edit the menu with the menu editor.
2. Menus are hierarchies, so a `Menu` object is both the root of the menu, but also the object that's stored in a `MenuItem`'s `submenu`. If you want to replace a menu item's submenu, just tell it to: `aMenuItem submenu: myNewMenu`. So you don't need to actually modify the sub-sub-sub menu that you try to modify. You can also create a new `Menu` object and just replace the sub-menu. When you create a `Menu` you can use the following code:

   myNewMenu := Menu new
   addItem: firstItem;
   addItem: secondItem;
   addLine;
   addItem: thirdItem;
   yourself.
   mySubmenu menu: myNewMenu.

So with `#addItem:` you can add your existing items to a new menu. And with `#addLine` you can tell the menu to create a new group and create a separator line.

If you need in-depth information on how to deal with Menus, i'd suggest you look at the GUIDevGuide.pdf in your VisualWorks' installation's `doc` folder. Chapter 7 is all about Menus.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, I knew there had to be a correct way of doing it, instead of my ugly brute force. I just got this task shoved down my thorat since my boss think Im a "computer guy". I will look in to creating a new menu and replace the old one, since I hate ugly code.

Answer (score 0):

In ArrayedCollection i found "growToAtLeast:" that could increase the capacity of groupSizes.

```
...groupSizes growToAtLeast: 2.
...groupSizes at: 1 put: 4.
...groupSizes at: 2 put: 1.
..etc..
```

I'm not sure this is the correct way, and I also dont know why I increased the size to 2, to get 4 index. But it works. Pleace tell me if this is the wrong way.